# WCAG 2.5.2 Pointer cancellation Abort or undo

Tags: accessibility

I want to know what is abort or undo  in Wcag 2.5.2 pointer cancellation. My understanding about Abort or undo, it is refers to when I click on checkout button and drag the mouse outside clickable area and release the mouse- so it is abort and undo means if I select checkout button and I want to delete that transaction so i click on delete- so it means undo.
can somebody please correct me, provide me some example website for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WCAG 2.5.2, "Pointer Cancellation," the guideline refers to the need for users to be able to easily cancel or undo pointer-based interactions, such as clicking on a button or link. This is particularly important for users with mobility or dexterity disabilities, who may accidentally click on something they didn't intend to, and need an easy way to correct their mistake.

Abort refers to the ability to cancel an action before it is fully completed. For example, if a user accidentally clicks on a "Delete" button, they should be able to easily cancel that action before it is fully executed, to prevent accidental deletion of important data.

Undo refers to the ability to reverse an action after it has been completed. For example, if a user accidentally deletes a file, they should be able to easily undo that action to restore the file to its previous state.

Here are a few examples of how these concepts might be implemented on a website:

1. When a user submits a form, provide a "Cancel" button that allows them to cancel the submission before it is fully processed. This could be especially helpful for long or complex forms where users may accidentally hit the submit button before they are finished.
2. When a user clicks on a link that takes them to a new page, provide a "Back" button or link that allows them to undo the navigation and return to the previous page.
3. When a user performs an action that has potentially serious consequences, such as deleting a file or canceling an order, provide a confirmation dialog that allows them to abort the action before it is fully executed.
4. When a user makes changes to a document or other content, provide an "Undo" button or keyboard shortcut that allows them to easily reverse those changes if necessary.

To see these concepts in action, you can check out some examples on websites such as Google Docs, Microsoft Word, or Trello. These sites all provide various ways to cancel or undo actions, such as "Undo" buttons, confirmation dialogs, and "Cancel" buttons for form submissions.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.  have a doubt regarding undo - confirmation dialog, it is same as wcag 3.3.4 Error prevention.

Comment: I suppose as per forum's rules, you might need to start a separate question for that.